# check if VA_ARGS has some value

Tags: c, gcc

I am writing a piece of code, where I have to make a decision depending on the number of parameters passed to the function. I am putting the situation I am facing in a simplified manner.

```
#define MYTRACE
#define MYTRACE1

#define TRACE(_var1_, _var2_, ...) \
MYTRACE(_var1_, _var2_, ##__VA_ARGS__)

int main(void) {
// your code goes here
int a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4;
TRACE(a,b);
TRACE(a,b,c);
TRACE(a,b,c,d); // TRACE can accept any no of arguments. Min 2
return 0;
}
```

Here, if TRACE had **only 2 arguments**, then I have to call `MYTRACE1`. In all the other cases I have to call `MYTRACE`. I am trying to achieve it with the help of `##__VA_ARGS__`. Can you please help.

Thanks

Chid